# Can't cast to unsupported type 'DateTimeOffset' DataServiceContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, odata, dataservice

I'm trying to update a remote table using `DataServiceContext` like it shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.updateobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

on other tables, this method worked fine for me but now I'm getting this error:

> Can't cast to unsupported type 'DateTimeOffset'

This is my code:

```
decimal hungerPercent = selectedWeight / (selectedDailyPercent * selectedPortionHeads * _batchWeight); //some calculation

var DeliveryGroup = _container.DeliveryGroups
                           .Where(x => x.GroupCode == selectedGroupCode && x.Branch == branch).First();

DeliveryGroup.HungerPercent = hungerPercent;                       

_container.UpdateObject(DeliveryGroup);
_container.SaveChanges();
```

and the table structure looks like this
[image]